# Trying to use mathjax in svg

Tags: svg, mathjax

I'm trying to make a svg gràfic in my web page. I want to write in it a LaTeX formula using mathjax but it doesn't work. Here is my code, althought I think it is not the problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

```
<svg height="250" width="450" > 
    <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="450" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" ></line>
    <line x1="230" y1="200" x2="230" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
    <path d="M 313 200 A 283 283 0 0 0  230 0 l -200 200 m 100 -100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <text x="10" y="30" style="fill:blue;font-size:10px">$\sqrt{2}$</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: you can probably access that text node explicitly in javascript and apply mathjax but that's not really on topic here, the mathjax tag link above has links to the mathjax help forum and mathjax tag at stackoverflow which might be better

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks!

Comment: but to get valid svg with embedded html or mathml you will want to use `<foreignObject` rather than `<text` (that might be enough to solve your issue I'd try a foreign object with an html `<span>` with the mathjax latex-code : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: Thank you David. It worked!